# How to improve the execution time of this program?

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, math, runtime

I want to find the lowest hop count from source to destination. My output is correct but the execution time of my program is like 1.0015 seconds when given 100000 entries. But I need to do the program within 1 second time frame. I have tried a lot to reduce the execution time but couldn't. Can anybody help me to achieve an execution time within 1 sec.

Sample Input-  1 10 2

Sample Output- 5

P.S- The program is executed remotely. The number of inputs can be <= 100000;

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int n, i, j, k, h,count=0,l=0;
    scanf("%u", &n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%u %u %u", &j, &k, &h);
        l=j;
        count = 0;
        while(l<=k)
        {
          if(l%h==0)
          {
            count=count+1;
          }
          l++;
        }
        printf("%u\n", count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would be better in [CodeReview.SE]?

Comment: What is the intent of this code?

Comment: The input will be source point, destination point and the hop-distance. Output will be number of hop counts to reach the destination. Eg- Input- 1,10,2 Output = 5;

Comment: At the given state of this question, it is not a good Code Review question. Questions on Code Review *should provide a sufficient description for what the code does.* Add a good description for the code and it can be posted on CR.

Comment: What is the definition of a "hop"?  Why is this 5 and not 4?

Comment: Have you tried using something faster than `scanf()` and `printf()`?

Comment: The answer is 5 because if a person starts hopping from 1 with a hop-distance of 2 then he will reach destination which is at 10 in exactly 5 hops.

Comment: Isn't the answer just something like (k-j+h-1)/h?

Comment: @ArindrajitChakraborty: Well, not exactly 5, seeing as 5 hops of size 2 would take you to 11.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz: Yeah, slowly iterating from `j` to `k` and doing a modulo every step may be the slowest possible way to solve this problem.

Comment: No. As there is a constraint that the person has to land in places or points which is a multiple of the hop count. If you apply that logic then it will eventually provide a wrong output when subjected to lots and lost of entries. I have tried using this logic previously but it fails after some point.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Learn how to debug using `gdb` & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Once your program is debugged, compile it with optimizations (`gcc -Wall -O2`). Then learn how to profile it (e.g. using `gprof` or `oprofile`...)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth- The problem is to find the minimum hop counts to reach the destination. After 4 hop counts it will reach to 9. The destination is at 10.

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction in your comments. Is the problem just to hop by 2's starting at 1, `1->3 3->5 5->7 7->9 9->11`. Or can you only hop to multiples of 2, `1->2 2->4 4->6 6->8 8->10`. Both will result in 5 hops for the example, but the calculations are different for the general case.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the `count` variable without the `while` loop, which seems to count how many elements in `[j, k]` are divisible by `h` (or, equivalently, are multiples of `h`).

To do this, use the facts that:

1. The amount of numbers lower than or equal to `x` that are divisible by `k` is given by the integer part of `x / k`, not counting `0`.
2. If `f(x, k) = int(x / k)`, then the amount of numbers in `[j, k]` that are divisible by `h` is given by `f(k, h) - f(j - 1, h)`.